# how to built a new data with summarize and cut command for each age group

Tags: r, cut, summarize

I want to build new data (age_summary) with a total number of people by age group. I would like to use "cut" and My codes are:

```
set.seed(12345)

#create a numeric variable Age       
AGE <- sample(0:110, 100, replace = TRUE)

# Creat Data fame
Sample.data <-data.frame(AGE)

age_summary <- Sample.data %>%  summarize(group_by(Sample.data,
                                                   cut(
                                                     AGE,
                                                     breaks=c(0,0.001, 0.083, 2, 13, 65,1000),
                                                     right=TRUE,
                                                     labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)","Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)","Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)","Child(2-12.999 yrs)", "Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)","Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)","Elderly(65-199 yrs)")
  ),"Total people" = n())
)
```

However my codes do not work. I am not sure what went wrong. Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Add:
I was able to get results that look like this:

[image]

is it possible for me to achieve something looks like this:
[image]

Here is what I get with adorn_totals(.) on a new data set. the total people looks OK, but the ave-age looks strange.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Can you remove the `summarise` wrapping around `group_by`

Comment: What is the 'Average Age' column

Comment: Also, how do you get 57.8 in Total, when the Average is 52.6 and 75

Comment: here is the codes that what I used: summary_data<- Sample.data %>% 
  group_by(grp =  cut(
    AGE,
    breaks=c(-Inf, 0,0.001, 0.083, 2, 13, 65,1000),
    right=TRUE,
    labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)","Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)","Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)","Child(2-12.999 yrs)", "Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)","Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)","Elderly(65-199 yrs)")
  )) %>% summarise(TotalPeople = n(), Ave_age=mean(AGE))%>% complete(grp = levels(grp), fill = list(TotalPeople = 0)). The 57.8 is the average age for those 13 people.

Comment: If you add `janitor::adorn_totals` at the end, it will create a row with total, but the mean of 52.6 and 75 should be around 63

Comment: Thanks for introduce me adorn_totals. :-) I updated my question again. The total people looks right, but the average age looks strange.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you need multiple functions, then use `%>% add_row(grp = "Total", TotalPeople = sum(.$TotalPeople), Ave_age = mean(.$Ave_age, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really learn a lot from your answers. You are  amazingly knowledgeable. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we remove the `summarise` wrapping around the `group_by`, we can find the issue more easily.  Here, the `cut` `labels` and `breaks` have different `lengths`, which can be changed if we add `-Inf` or `Inf` in `breaks`

```
library(dplyr)
Sample.data %>% 
      group_by(grp =  cut(AGE,
                              breaks=c(-Inf, 0,0.001, 0.083, 2, 13, 65,1000),
                              right=TRUE,
                              labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)",
     "Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)","Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)","Child(2-12.999 yrs)", "Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)",
                   "Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)","Elderly(65-199 yrs)")
   )) %>% 
     summarise(TotalPeople = n())
```

If we need to create a row with different functions applied on different columns, use `add_row`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
Sample.data %>% 
    group_by(grp = cut( AGE, breaks=c(-Inf, 0,0.001, 0.083, 2, 13, 65,1000), 
        right=TRUE, labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)","Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)","Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)","Child(2-12.999 yrs)", 
          "Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)","Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)","Elderly(65-199 yrs)") )) %>% 
    summarise(TotalPeople = n(), Ave_age=mean(AGE))%>%
    complete(grp = levels(grp), fill = list(TotalPeople = 0)) %>% 
    add_row(grp = "Total", TotalPeople = sum(.$TotalPeople),
                Ave_age = mean(.$Ave_age, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: You are right. Your answer makes the flow much clearer. I just start using r for a month and still struggling with how to write things in a correct flow. Thanks so much for helping. :-)

Comment: @Stataq Thank you.  One of the main purpose/advantage of `tidyverse` is that the `%>%` makes it easier to write the function and understand what you want to do next on the rhs of `%>%`  If we wrap everything, then `base R` would do the same purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question, do you know whether it is doable if I want to add a total at the end of row. If so, how? Also, when I get the sub total for each group, is it possible to keep the age groups even though it  has 0 count? Right now it only gave me the groups with at least 1 count. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Stataq  total at the end of row is not clear.  Here, we get a summarised output with `summarise`.  Do you need `mutate` instead of `summarise`.  Regarding the 0 counts, one opiton is to use `complete` after this step, i.e. %>% complete(grp = levels(grp), fill = list(TotalPeople = 0))`

Comment: I just updated my old question with picture that what I want to get. hope that helps. Thanks  again. And, yes, the Complete trick works.